# Caesars Cipher не работает

Tags: javascript

Не могу найти ошибку. Со знаками, не являющимися буквами, еще не разбирался.

```
function rot13(str) {

  for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    var symbCode = str.charCodeAt(i);

    if (symbCode >= 77) {
    symbCode -= 13;}

    else {
      symbCode += 13;}


    var symbFromCode = String.fromCharCode(symbCode); 
    str = str.replace(str[i], symbFromCode);

  }

  return str;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Comment: А в чем собственно ошибка у вас, скопировал ваш код, он выполнился без ошибок. Приведите пример входных данных и пример выходных.

Comment: Входные данные те же, а возвращает FEEE-PODR-CAMC вместо FREE-CODE-CAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    str = str.replace(str[i], symbFromCode);
```

Вы же заменяете не символ по конкретному индексу, а первое вхождение. После замены у вас каша произойдет:

SERR -> FERR

FERR -> FRRR

FRRR -> FERR //так как заменится первая R, а не вторая, как вы предполагаете

FERR -> FEER //и т.д.

Лучше формируйте новую строку в отдельной переменной и её возвращайте:

```
function rot13(str) {
  result = '';
  for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    var symbCode = str.charCodeAt(i);

    if (symbCode >= 77) {
    symbCode -= 13;}

    else {
      symbCode += 13;}


    var symbFromCode = String.fromCharCode(symbCode); 
    result = result + symbFromCode;

  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Ещё бы `for (var i = ...`. А то переменная «утекает»

Comment: Что значит "утекает"?

Comment: @Александр, без `var` переменная `i` будет глобальной. Это основы языка, нужно с ними быть знакомым, если вам об этом неизвестно, то рекомендую почитать.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться!